# Google Play Games Services Real Time Multiplayer

Tags: android, google-play-services, unity-game-engine

I am using Google Plays Games Service's Real-Time Multiplayer in my unity game. But i do not know how many players are supported at the same time if i use that services. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, Google Play games services supports a maximum of eight
>   players in a multiplayer game (including the player who is initiating
>   the match).

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer